# MATLAB coding in system of matrices

Tags: matlab

How can we find an unknown matrix from a system of known matrices in MATLAB? 
For example say we have

```
A=[-15 0; 0 -15], B = [8 2; 2 8], C=[2 1; 1 2],
```

and we have to find an unknown matrix P from equation

```
A(T)P + PA+P(t)BP+C = 0
```

Comment: I would recommend doing the math out by hand, (multiply both sides by P(T), do some rearranging, and you should be able to solve for P. It is pretty simple matrix math. No need to have MATLAB do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to solve the continuous algebraic Riccati equation.  Correct?  If so you're looking to use the `care` command, more info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/care.html).  You could also look into the `dare` command for discrete time.